# wpf анимация движения тока по электрической цепи

Tags: c#, wpf

Хотелось бы создать анимацию движения тока по электрической цепи.
С движением одного объекта вдоль пути проблем нет , пример кода привел, а вот как изобразить движение тока не могу сообразить. Есть идеи ?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="pathg">
        <PathFigure IsClosed="False">
            <PolyLineSegment Points="0,0 220,0 220,175 0,175" />
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Viewbox >

            <Canvas Margin="10"   Width="200" Height="200">
                <Path Stroke="Red" Data="{StaticResource pathg}" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" />
                <Ellipse Name="ellipse1" Width="15" Height="15" Canvas.Top="180" Canvas.Left="120">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.3, 0.3">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                    <Ellipse.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                   Duration="0:0:4" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathg}" Source="Y" >
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                   Duration="0:0:4" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   PathGeometry="{StaticResource pathg}" Source="X" >
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Ellipse.Triggers>
                </Ellipse>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox >

</Grid>
```

Пример схемы. Хотелось бы к ней добавить движение тока
[image: пример схемы]

Comment: Анимируйте 1000 объектов по этому пути с небольшим отставанием друг от друга

Comment: @АндрейNOP по моему это сложное, потому тупиковое решение . потому и задал вопрос на SO.

Comment: Ну тогда расскажите как вы хотите видеть это

Comment: как должно выглядеть движение тока ?

Comment: видео с 37 секунды https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=148&v=vcXZylSj9DI&feature=emb_logo

Comment: @АндрейNOP наверное все таки придется делать как вы говорите.